# angular + php login api cors issue

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cors

I am trying to do login in angular + php rest api, api is working in postman. I have added cors in php, same code is working with other site but now I am getting the below error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.yapp.tk/demo/kloxet/customers/login.json. Request header
>   field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
$http({
            url: 'http://www.yapp.tk/demo/kloxet/customers/login.json',
            method: "POST",
            data: { email: $scope.username, password: $scope.password },
            //withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
        }, 
        function(response) { // optional
                // failed
        });
```

Comment: It's failing on authentication. Make a call from postman and match the headers that they are the same. If you are logged in browser then may be postman will not yell on the authentication.

Comment: In postman everything is working fine

Comment: then just check the headers that every thing is matching.. How ever it's not angular complaining about it it's your php api.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set cros allow from php. It has nothing to do with angular. Check for cros filter in php. And it's yelling on preflight when your application is doing an option request. It can depend on if you are doing basic authentication from php and it's doing authentication even on the option request witch it should not do.